# Setting Text Color on all items in IBOutletCollection 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I have several IBOutlet and use them with IBOutletCollection :

```
    @interface IBOutletCollectionViewController : UIViewController {


    IBOutletCollection (UILabel) NSArray *multipleLabels;

}

@property (nonatomic , retain) IBOutletCollection (UILabel) NSArray *multipleLabels;

@end
```

but when I want use the UILable properties the compiler gives this error :

> request for member 'textColor' in
>   something not a structure or union

I think it's because of NSArray ! is there any solution for that ?

Comment: Could you post code how you try to set property?

Comment: for example : "multipleLabels.textColor = [UIColor redColor];"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) to set the property on each label instance in the array:

```
[multipleLabels setValue:[UIColor redColor] forKey:@"textColor"];
```

"IBOutletCollection(UILabel)" can be omitted in the iVar declaration as long as it's used in the property declaration.

Another option is to call "makeObjectsPerformSelector:" on the NSArray instance:

```
[multipleLabels makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setTextColor:) withObject:[UIColor redColor]];
```